# Npm install from repo not running `prepare`

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, npm-scripts

I have an npm package for common components hosted on an internal git server. For some reason when I call `npm install` in another project I want to consume this in it will not run the `prepare` hook. Obviously, this does not work since the npm package needs a `/dist` folder in node_modules to be able to consume the package.

I have already tried things such as using the deprecated `prepublish` hook and even that does not get called. I also tried to do `postinstall` to see if I could build after install, while that hook did get called it failed because the devDependencies were not installed

package.json

```
{
  "name": "common-components",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "scripts": {
    "prepare": "npm run build",
    "build": "ng build",
    ...
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    ...
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    ...
  },
}
```

command being used for install

```
npm install --save git+ssh://{URL-to-common-components-repo}}
```

I have read through the npm-scripts documentation https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts thoroughly and it seems like they insist that `prepare` hook should always be called for this exact use-case

## Updated 5/6/2019

Just as a note I found this bug on NPM community https://npm.community/t/using-npm-ci-does-not-run-prepare-script-for-git-modules/632/4.

I am using npm 6.4.1 which should work according to the bug

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For those that are wondering the status of this. I was unable to ever get it to work. What I ended up doing was hosting the components on a private npm registry and that works fine since the `npm publish` command will do the build and only publish the dist folder

Comment: Something needs to change. Every solution to every npm problem I've had the last few years is put it on the npm registry.

Comment: In 2021... it's still a snafu. `prepare` script is well-documented as the correct solution for setting up git dependencies. But it just never runs...

Comment: After being bitten by this, I realized `prepare` is just not designed to work this way (it would be nice thou!). They intend it for use during publishing or while developing the package locally. We switched to preparing a tarball manually, uploading it to Github, and then installing from the tarball's URL. See more [here](https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/1287#issuecomment-1809381099).

Answer (score 14):

One thing to check that hit me on a package recently - if there is a .gitignore and not .npmignore npm may be ignoring your /dist folder. Adding an empty .npmignore worked in this case.

> "If there’s no .npmignore file, but there is a .gitignore file, then
>   npm will ignore the stuff matched by the .gitignore file. If you want
>   to include something that is excluded by your .gitignore file, you can
>   create an empty .npmignore file to override it."

from https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/developers

Comment: Good catch, that was it.

Comment: WOW. What a find. I'm not sure if I agree with the default "use gitignore" approach especially in the case where one would want /dist to be ignored in git but never ignored in npm.

Answer (score 3):

If adding an empty `.npmignore` does not help, you can try specifying all files in dist explicitly in `package.json#files`. If this works you might want to consider using a wildcard pattern that matches the files in dist to simplify the `package.json`.

package.json

```json
    ...
    "files": [
        "source",
        "dist/cjs/main.js",
        "dist/es/main.js"
    ]
}
```

see this comment to a similar issue in the npm/cli repository https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/1287#issuecomment-635021757

Comment: [here](https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/6031#issuecomment-1449119423) they explain a bit more how the prepare script is supposed to work. Run `npm pack --dry-run` in your repo to see which files will be included when installed.

Answer (score 0):

It's very likely that your `dist/` folder is in your `.gitignore` file. According to [this response](https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/3800#issuecomment-1050338941) from an npm-cli maintainer:

> In order to be able to properly prepare a git repo npm will run the
> extracted files through npm-packlist in order to get the expected
> files that are going to be placed in your node_modules folder.

Further checking the documentation of [npm-packlist](https://github.com/npm/npm-packlist#npm-packlist), we find that npm-packlist will respect the `.gitignore` file if it has nothing else to go off of:

> If there's no package.json with a files list, and there's no
> .npmignore file, but there is a .gitignore file, then ignore all the
> files in the .gitignore file.

[This article](https://zellwk.com/blog/ignoring-files-from-npm-package/) further expands on the idea.

It seems to me that the best fix is to explicitly declare the files that your package needs (including `dist/`) in the [files](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/configuring-npm/package-json#files) section of your `package.json` file. Then you have complete control over what's included and the package size is minimized.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `root` user to `npm install` the package then the prepare script might not be triggered. The reason was the `prepare` child process has no permission to run (user account was set to default of 'nobody' when using npm with root). You can read more here: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/17346

To fix this, in the lib package, create an `.npmrc` file and add:

```
unsafe-perm: true
```

Answer (score -1):

Adding `main` in the package.json fixed this issue for me.

```
    "main": "./dist/index.js",
    "scripts": {
       "build": "babel src --out-dir dist",
       "prepare": "npm run build",
       "lint": "eslint ."
     },
```

`node v14.15.4` `npm 6.14.11`