# how to correctly install a forked repo?

Tags: npm, ngx-extended-pdf-viewer

I forked this [ngx-extended-pdf-viewer](https://github.com/stephanrauh/ngx-extended-pdf-viewer) and I'm trying to install it.

The npm scripts in its [package.json](https://github.com/stephanrauh/ngx-extended-pdf-viewer/blob/main/package.json) looks like this

```
"scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --deployUrl=/path/ --host 10.0.1.3 --disable-host-check",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "unix-package": "ng b ngx-extended-pdf-viewer && rm -r dist && ng-packagr -p projects/ngx-extended-pdf-viewer/ng-package.json",
    "showcase": "npm run unix-package && rm -r ../extended-pdf-viewer-showcase/node_modules/ngx-extended-pdf-viewer && cp -R dist/ngx-extended-pdf-viewer ../extended-pdf-viewer-showcase/node_modules/ngx-extended-pdf-viewer",
    "issue": "npm run unix-package && rm -r ../ngx-extended-pdf-viewer-issues/issue317-ng9/node_modules/ngx-extended-pdf-viewer && cp -R dist/ngx-extended-pdf-viewer ../ngx-extended-pdf-viewer-issues/issue317-ng9/node_modules/ngx-extended-pdf-viewer",
    "win-package": "ng b ngx-extended-pdf-viewer && rmdir dist /S && ng-packagr -p projects/ngx-extended-pdf-viewer/ng-package.json",
    "release": "npm run unix-package && cd dist/ngx-extended-pdf-viewer && npm publish && cd .. && cd .. && ./createTag.sh && node ./increase-version-number.js",
    "cypress": "./node_modules/.bin/cypress open"
  },
```

But it's not being installed,The error looks like this
[image]

I've search around the internet, and based from the answers is to add a npm script `prepare`.

So i added a `prepare` script:

```
"unix-package": "ng b ngx-extended-pdf-viewer && rm -r dist && ng-packagr -p projects/ngx-extended-pdf-viewer/ng-package.json",
"prepare": "npm run unix-package"
```

What it basically does is it packages the one under `projectsngx-extended-pdf-viewer` subfolder.

I've also added a empty `.npmignore` as advised [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60718312/9732932) since the `/dist` folder is added in `.gitignore`.

Still doesn't work as expected. Hope to get help from you guys, i've been stuck on this problem for days.

Comment: What do you mean by not installed correctly? What is the error you get? What command are you using to install it?

Comment: Sorry, i think i've worded it incorrectly before. It is not actually being installed, it was a mistake on my part. 
I've updated the post to add explanation and screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for answering late - but here's a discussion covering and answering your question: https://github.com/stephanrauh/ngx-extended-pdf-viewer/discussions/910